# Does $f \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $p$ is a prime number and $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, $deg f(x)=n$. If $f(x)$ has $n+1$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Does $f \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is true of any field:

> Let $K$ be a field and $f \in K[x]$ of degree $n$. Then $f$ has at most $n$ roots in $K$.

This follows from this fact, which in turn follows from Euclidean division:

> If $a \in K$ and $f(a)=0$, then $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$.

Note that $f \in K[x]$ of degree $n$ implies $f\ne0$.